# Fluent validation, set the minimum value in case property has value less then

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I'm using fluent validation in order to validate certain model.

```
public class CarModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CarModel>
{
    public CarModelValidator ()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        // RuleFor(x => x.NrOfDoors)....
    }
}
```

is it possible to validate `CarModel` and it's property `NrOfDoors`, and if its less than `2` to set the value to be 2. Or fluent validation is not meant for that? Is it just for validate the model and informing the user and not for setting the values?

Comment: Best practice is that validation via any class library or tools do only the validation task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is that validation via any class library or tools do **only** the validation task and It is based on [Separation_of_concerns](https://www.castsoftware.com/blog/how-to-implement-design-pattern-separation-of-concerns) pattern.

But if you need to make sure `NrOfDoors` property has maximum value by `2` you can use full property like this:

```
public class CarModel
{
    private int nrOfDoors;

    public int NrOfDoors
    {
        get { return nrOfDoors; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 2)
                nrOfDoors = 2;
            else
                nrOfDoors = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `RuleFor(x => x.NrOfDoors).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(2)` should do the trick

Comment: that's not the answer to my question. You don't set the value anywhere in this code

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't really fit to your question, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the **real** answer is:  It is not meant for that. Validation is an intermediate step to deny a value change and inform the user if the rule(s) would be broken.